# onSnapshot not working when exceeds limit in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to limit the number of messages showing in my web app, when I tried `limit` with `orderBy` it stops showing new messages after crossing its limit (i.e. 15), so where I am doing wrong?

PS: I tried `orderBy("createdAt", "desc")` , and it shows the new messages but in descending order

Code :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = db
      .collection("messages")
      .orderBy("createdAt")
      .limit(15)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setMessages(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, msg: doc.data() }))
        );
      });
    return unsub;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with append-only lists, you can limit the number of values returned initially, but still get future adds by using limitToLast():

```
db.collection("...")
  .orderBy("timestamp")
  .limitToLast(3)
  .onSnapshot(change => console.log(change.type, change.doc.id));
```

[Here's a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-typescript-query-feed?file=index.ts)

Comment: Yeah thanks it's working , but check this also [code](https://github.com/fireship-io/react-firebase-chat/blob/master/src/App.js), i mean how it's working

Comment: @Kato: Huh? When did Firestore add `limitToLast()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are establishing a listener for changes on ONLY those 15 documents - you've already limited which documents are being monitored.  The query is doing EXACTLY what it's supposed to be doing.  It doesn't SOUND like that's really what you want.

Your COULD just do a fetch (`.get()`) on 15 documents, then use a `.startAfter().get()` to get the next set, based on whatever event you want (clicks, etc).

IF (big if) you need to monitor changes on sub-sets of documents, then you'll need to REMOVE the listener on your first set of documents, and create a NEW listener on the next set of documents.

Remember: `onSnapShot()` is a LISTENER, listening for changes.  If that isn't really a requirment, just use a `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

If think you're looking to show the 15 **newest** messages, which means you'll want to order on *descending* creation:

```
db
  .collection("messages")
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  ...
```

If you then still want to show the newest message at the bottom, you'll have to reverse the messages in your application code.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was thinking but then how this work [code](https://github.com/fireship-io/react-firebase-chat/blob/master/src/App.js)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. Did you add a `"desc"` to that code? What changed when you did that?

Comment: I mean check the link given in my comment above